# How to align the bottom of 3 JLabels that are held in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, alignment

I am trying to align the bottom of 3 JLabels that contain an image. The 3 JLabels are held in one big JPanel. 
[I found a tutorial about GUI using Java Swing here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) But for some reason if i apply the example code (that is given for buttons) it doesn't work on the JLabels or JPanel.
This is the example code from the Oracle website:

```
button1.setAlignmentY(Component.BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT);
button2.setAlignmentY(Component.BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT);
```

Any idea what went wrong? I could send my code, but I thought maybe that would make it too confusing for what might be a simple answer too an easy question for most of you out here.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

```
public class LayoutOef_01 extends JFrame{

    JPanel paneel;
    JLabel label1, label2, label3;
    ImageIcon pic1, pic2, pic3;
    Border panelBord, labelBord;


    public Layout_01(String titel){
        super(titel);

        paneel = new JPanel();

        pic1 = new ImageIcon("images/simon1.png");
        pic2 = new ImageIcon("images/simon2.png");
        pic3 = new ImageIcon("images/simon3.png");

        label1 = new JLabel(pic1);
        label2 = new JLabel(pic2);
        label3 = new JLabel(pic3);

        paneel.add(label1);
        paneel.add(label2);
        paneel.add(label3);

        panelBoord = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE, 30);
        paneel.setBorder(panelBord);
        paneel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        labelBoord = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2);
        label1.setBorder(labelBord);
        label2.setBorder(labelBord);
        label3.setBorder(labelBord);

        this.getContentPane().add(paneel);
        this.pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Layout_01 lay1 = new LayoutOef_01("Layout_01");
        lay1.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

So i tried placing the following code -in different places- inside the code above, but nothing changes:

```
label1.setAlignmentY(Component.BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT);
label2.setAlignmentY(Component.BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT);
label3.setAlignmentY(Component.BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT);
```

Comment: Add your code.  It could be an issue with `Glue`, it could be that `BoxLayout` is configured to stack everything vertically instead of horizontally.

Comment: How can your code be too confusing? It should be about 20 lines of code to test this. If it works for buttons it should work for labels. Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this sample: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.awt/ComponentBOTTOMALIGNMENT.htm

Remember to:
- set the layout on the panel.
- set the alignment on the button
- add the button to the panel.

Comment: Not enough stackflow-rep to answer my own question this fast after asking it, but the BoxLayout and example indeed did the trick.

Comment: didnt get bottom alignment   http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.awt/ComponentBOTTOMALIGNMENT.htm link is wrong